# Отключить интерактивность маркеров объектов на подложке карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

На карте yandex 2.1 есть объекты (рестораны, парковки и т.д.) по щелчку на них появляется подробности о них и как проехать туда.

Нужно, чтобы эти подробности не появлялись. т.е.  чтобы вообще щелчок мышью на них не работал.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4):

Интерактивность маркеров POI на подложке можно отключить опцией карты [`yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#param-options.yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity?from=SO).

```js
var myMap;

// Дождёмся загрузки API и готовности DOM.
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  // Создание экземпляра карты и его привязка к контейнеру с
  // заданным id ("map").
  myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    // При инициализации карты обязательно нужно указать
    // её центр и коэффициент масштабирования.
    center: [55.76, 37.64], // Москва
    zoom: 10
  }, {
    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search',
    yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity: true
  });
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, все работает

Comment: не стесняйтесь пометить ответ, как правильный :)